# Using jQuery flip, can't get revert flip to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

Morning! The following is (I know not the best) jQuery code using the [Flip!](http://lab.smashup.it/flip/) jQuery plugin. The original flip fires fine, but the revert flip will not function for the life of me. I've tried tons of different things, but no success. This is what I currently have.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    $('.flip1').bind("click",function(){
        var elem = $(".toflip");
        if(elem.data('flipped')){
            elem.revertFlip();
            elem.data('flipped',false)
        } else {
            elem.flip({
                direction:'lr',
                dontChangeColor: true,
                onBefore: function(){
                    elem.html(elem.siblings('#flip1Data').html());
                }
            });
            elem.data('flipped',true);
        }
    });
    $('.flip2').bind("click",function(){
        var elem = $(".toflip");
        if(elem.data('flipped')){
            elem.revertFlip();
            elem.data('flipped',false)
        } else {
            elem.flip({
                direction:'lr',
                dontChangeColor: true,
                onBefore: function(){

                    elem.html(elem.siblings('#flip2Data').html());

                }
            });
            elem.data('flipped',true);
        }
    });
    $("#flip1back").bind("click",function(){
        $('.toflip').revertFlip();
        return false;
    });
    $("#flip2back").bind("click",function(){
        $('.toflip').revertFlip();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Your final goal is to bind flip on click or it's an intermediate step to i.e. flip on mouse hover and flip back on mouse out? In this case, I'd like to suggest you this code: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip (pure CSS flip).

Comment: sir, this on on click... never a hover or anything of that sort. Also, this needs to work in IE8

Answer (score 0):

The following code performs left and reverse flip. If you want to change flip direction, simply change `direction` property on JS code. Don't forget to upload necessary JS files to your folder (you can see them at the bottom of HTML code). Here's a link to the [**working example**](http://testinternet.altervista.org/flip/).

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.button#left {
    background-color:green;
}
.button#revert {
    background-color:red;
    display:none;
}
#flipbox {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
    background-color: #ff9000;
    font-family: 'ChunkFive Regular', Tahoma, Helvetica;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flipbox">front content</div>
<div class="button" id="left">left</div>
<div class="button" id="revert">revert</div>


<!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("#left").bind("click",function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $("#flipbox").flip({
                direction: "rl",
                color: "#39AB3E",
                content: "back content",
                onBefore: function(){$("#revert").css('display','inline-block');}
            })
            return false;
        });

        $("#revert").bind("click",function(){
            $("#flipbox").revertFlip();
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Revert button is shown only after first left flip: there's no way to revert a flip if you still haven't do it :) Code and working example are up to date.

Comment: I've used your code yet revert STILL will not fire.

Comment: Added link to working example, and updated code to show revert button only after first flip. Now works fine.